# Trying to add In app browser

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I am trying to create a browser within my app that will allow me to click a link and initiate a download of a file, if I create it as a webview this does not work it simply opens the file, I have seen examples on other apps where there seems to be a browser in the app not just a webview. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: basically what you would do is create a UIWebView and add it onto a UIViewController. You could get the "browser" look by adding a UIToolbar to the bottom of the view controller, and creating custom actions within the UIWebView for whatever you'd like. \

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` delegate method to intercept load requests and handle them accordingly.  For example, if a URL meets your standards, you could return `NO` and instead download that manually through your application.